Nextjs middleware not being evoked
I have a mono repo project working with NX. All is working fine, but I tried to add a middleware and it isn't being caught in the requests.
I tried to put it in all different places and with _ in the name as well, but no luck.
Does anyone know what could be wrong here?
Here is an image of my project and the middleware distribution.
I'm using Nextjs 14.0.4

This is the code of my middleware:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export default function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  console.log('MIDDELWAREEEE');
  const publicPaths = ['/login', '/register'];

  if (publicPaths.includes(pathname)) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  const token = request.cookies.get('auth_token');
  console.log('token', token);
  if (!token) {
    return redirectToLogin(request);
  }

  if (!token.value) {
    return redirectToLogin(request);
  }
}

function redirectToLogin(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
  url.pathname = '/login';
  return NextResponse.redirect(url);
}


So after some days, I could reach the solution. I hope it helps someone in the future.
In next.config.js, if you altered the page extensions, like I did, to:
pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'api.ts'],

I had to add an entry to cover page.ts:
pageExtensions: ['page.tsx','page.ts', 'api.ts'],

Finally added the middleware as middleware.page.ts, at pages level, and it started working.
In sum, the middleware must match the pageExtensions defined on next.config.js

The middleware file must be at the same level as pages folder, also no need to do default export.
you can check this official docs provided by nextjs

So, the middleware is already on the same level as pages.

and have you changed it to do normal export and it didn't work?

Yes, the normal over default export didn't have effect, only when I changed the next.config.js
